# Is there a way to assign proxy settings for each tab using the chrome.proxy API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I found out that you can make Chrome use a proxy using the chrome.proxy api. However this changes the proxy settings for the whole Browser. Is it possible to assign proxies to certain tabs?

Comment: No, there's no way.